# CSS selector performance

Tags: css

I know the performance difference is miniscule, but which is a faster CSS selector?

```
div.class{ }
```

or

```
.class{ }
```

Comment: I'm just putting this as a comment, because I don't know for sure, but I *believe* div.class is faster.

Comment: Argh, not this again... brb finding duplicates.

Comment: read this [excellent post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/), it'll learn you alot. For instance that you just shouldn't care ;) any performance gained is totally irrelevant compared to the profit gained by optimizing your javascript and connection speed (caching, image sprites, fast cdn's etc.). Interesting question though!

Comment: The synopsis - if you're using jQuery or another selector library, use use $('div.class'), it's generally faster.  If it's just raw CSS, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4):

The performance difference is *so* minuscule (if detectable at all) that it's not worth even thinking about.

Use `div.class` if you need some styles to only apply to `div` elements with that class, use `.class` otherwise. Base your decision on what your styling needs are, not some infinitesimal performance benefit.

<sub>Note: There are *some* selectors that really are (relatively) slow and might be worth changing, things like `.class > *`. *But*, even for selectors with really bad performance, and even if you're at a reasonable stage in your project to start thinking about optimizing things, there are exactly a million things you should worry about first before you get to CSS selector optimization.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

CSS Selectors are parsed right to left, and then displayed, and the full rule is always parsed. So that would lead me to believe that `.class` is slightly quicker than `div.class`. That said, there's also the time taken to render the page, so it may depend on how many elements have that class and how complex the rule is.

Now with all of **that** said, check out the first answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: The right-to-left evaluation of CSS selectors is not done on the compound selector level as far as I know. Implementations may not necessarily check classes first before types. Also, most browsers don't bother continuing once they arrive at a node that *doesn't* match a component of a selector, so most selectors aren't parsed fully.

Comment: Yep. Completely unimportant, but it's not the bottleneck, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Interesting. The more you know. ≈≈≈☆

Answer (score 2):

I think it may depend on browser, you can check selectors here:
http://jsperf.com/jquery-performance-bn/3

In my browser (Opera 11.62) div.class was a lot faster.

Comment: I'd heard that 'div.class' is faster because the browser or javascript library only iterates through divs to check the selector, whereas with '.class' it iterates through all DOM elements.  This appears to hold true for the Sizzle selector engine at least :)

Answer (score 0):

`.class {}` selector is faster than `div.class {}` because in the first case browser only checks that the element **has** specified class, whereas in the second case it additionally has to check the element **is** actually a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even remember asking this question at this point, but here's the jist:

The performance difference is minute, EXCEPT when using a JS library like jQuery.  To evaluate $('.class'), jQuery checks all elements in the DOM.  To evaluate $('div.class'), it only checks divs.  So depending on the size of the DOM and the elements in it, the performance difference can be pretty significant.

So really, the pure CSS performance is almost exactly the same, but performance when run though a Javascript selector engine can be noticeably different. I *think* that is what I was aiming for when I asked this.  Thanks to everyone for your comments, you all get upvotes :)