# When would a "slow" CSS selector affect performance?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Let's say we have a style declaration like this:

```
body > div > input:hover ~ label {
    color: red;
}
```

The way I understand it, the parser would find all labels, filter which ones follow a hovered `input` which is a direct descendant of a `div` which is a direct descendant of `body`.

What I'm curious to know is whether this will be done whenever the hover state of the input changes or only once one document load (placed in a lookup table of some kind).

If I want to use massive, complex selectors (for irrelevant reasons), would the rendering of the page be slower between states and effects or would only the page's initial load time be affected?

Comment: beside performance, cross browser compatibility will also be an issue. (e.g. `~` General sibling selector is available since CSS3 only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: I am aware of that, was just using it as an example.

Comment: Although this is a bit old, this [post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/) worths to read.

Comment: "What I'm curious to know is whether this will be done whenever the hover state of the input changes or only once one document load (placed in a lookup table of some kind)." This sort of stuff is up to the implementation, really - your chances of getting answers will mostly depend on referring to the documentation or even the source if available.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the answers of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420269/css-selector-performance), CSS performance difference is not significant. However, if you use JS libraries like jQuery to select element, performance varies a lot if using the same selector.

Also, performance will vary if the CSS is minified or not, combined into 1 file / multiple files.

In theory, in slow Internet connection, CSS file size also affects loading performance, but CSS is often very small in file size, thus this can be safely ignored, unless you concern those users with 56K modem.